# Show that $\lim_{a \to \infty} \sup_{n} \int_0^{T-a}||v_{n,r}(t+a)-v_{n,r}(t)||_{\mathbb{L}^2(\Omega_{2r})}^2dt=0.$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, normed-spaces

Let $\ 0 \leq t \leq t+a \leq T$, with
$$\lim_{a \to 0} \sup_{n} \int_0^{T-a}\left\|u_n(t+a)-u_n(t)\right\|_{\mathbb{L}^2(\Omega_{r})}^2dt=0,$$
where $\Omega_r=\Omega \cap \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2; |x|<r \right\}$, let $\phi \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^+)$ with $\phi(s)=1$ for $s \in [0,1]$ an $\phi(s)=0$ for $s \in [2,+\infty)$ and consider
\begin{eqnarray}
v_{n,r}: \Omega_{2r} \times [0,T] &\to& \mathbb{R}^2 \\
(x,t) &\to& \phi\left( \frac{|x|^2}{r^2}\right)u_n(x,t).
\end{eqnarray}
Show that
$$\lim_{a \to 0} \sup_{n} \int_0^{T-a}\|v_{n,r}(t+a)-v_{n,r}(t)\|_{\mathbb{L}^2(\Omega_{2r})}^2dt=0.$$

Comment: no,no, that is it, i want use only the first integral, i trying to prove some inequality....

Comment: tho problem it is the interval $(1,2)$

Comment: sorry, $a \to 0$, ok? edited!

Comment: I am still confused. In the above $u_n$ is defined on $[0,T]$ and further down it is defined on $\Omega_{2r} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: yes, but it is writen. I am still confused too

Comment: with that information I think is easier...

Comment: I give up. ${}{}{}{}$